Zsh - Join after split using `s` flag
I was reading about splitting using s flag and am trying to understand the behaviour of this command I wrote.
var='axb'
var1=${(s/x/)var}

Before printing var1 I will tell what I was expecting it to be. I thought it would be  similar to when an array is directly assigned to a variable - All the elements should have been joined with a space or the first character of $IFS (as written in the documentation).

23. Semantic joining
In contexts where expansion semantics requires a single word to result, all words are rejoined with the first character of IFS between. So in ‘${(P)${(f)lines}}’ the value of ${lines} is split at newlines, but then must be joined again before the ‘(P)’ flag can be applied.
If a single word is not required, this rule is skipped.

So, the behaviour for an array is as follows, similar to what is written above.
var=(a b)
IFS=q var1=${var}
echo $var1
> aqb

But in the case of splitting using the flag, the value isn't split and joined. Instead, the value is assigned as it is, like splitting never happened.
var='axb'
var1=${(s/x/)var}
echo $var1
> axb

Can someone explain what is the difference here? If there is a rule like splitting is not done if the output is expected to be a single word, then please provide documentation for that.
Also, is the reason same for the below as well?
var=a{b,c}d
echo $var
> a{b,c}d       # expected 'abd acd'


var=a{b,c}d => glob expansion doesn't happen in non-array assignments

Isn't {b,c} a brace expansion? In the documentation brace expansion and globbing (referred as filename expansion) are separate.

for var='axb' var1=${(s/x/)var}, it seems like you need to write var='axb'  var1="${${(s/x/)var}}"

Also, could you provide some documentation reference to prove your point. Any extract in the documentation.

Even var1=${${(s/x/)var}} (without double quotes) is working. I'm not getting it. Is nested substitution doing something?

Your right, it works without double quotes in an assignment, and you need those quotes in for eg. printf '%s\n' "${${(s/x/)var}}". BTW, var1=${(s/x/)var} not working might be a bug

Hey, @Fravadona. Can you upvote the question if you think it is good enough?

Just to note: IFS=q var1=${var} does not set IFS for the duration of the other assignment, because assignments aren't commands. It's just setting the value of IFS, period.

I"m not sure if or where this is documented, but I suspect the field splitting performed by s/.../ is similar to the field splitting perform by read, which is to say, no splitting occurs when there is only one target.

(Or rather, with one target, the string is "split" into one field.)
